# git lost commit after revert a commit and cherrypick it again

Tags: git, merge

I have two branches A/B:

1. Make a commit named `a` in branch `A`
2. Check out branch `B`, and merge `A`
3. Revert commit `a` (until now, `B` doesn't have commit `a` but `A` does)
4. Check out `A`, revert commit `a`, but re-commit `a` with `git cherry-pick a` (now `A` has commit `a'`)
5. Check out `B`, merge `A` to `B` again (the commit `a` or `a'` is lost)

I think finally, branch `B` will have the commit `a` or `a'` , but it lost. What's going on here?

I have checked the git docs, but it just mentions three way merge without any detail.

From https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_description:

> Then "`git merge topic`" will replay the changes made on the `topic` branch since it diverged from `master` (i.e., `E`) until its current commit (`C`) on top of `master`, and record the result in a new commit along with the names of the two parent commits and a log message from the user describing the changes. Before the operation, `ORIG_HEAD` is set to the tip of the current branch (`C`).

If it is an actual **replay** , the commit `a` should be on branch `B`.

Comment: Merging does not copy commits. It makes _one brand new commit_ out of nothing, based on the differences in both branches since the merge base. So the question is based on a misconception of what a merge is. You might want to read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/

Comment: And the original `a` is not "lost" but its effects are not going to be merged into B the second time, you can't merge the same commit into the same branch twice (the revert doesn't change that).

Comment: @matt, `Merging does not copy commits` - why not? In general, both with fast-forward and three-way merge you will see exactly those commits hashes that were in branch `A` after doing `git merge A`.

Comment: @Ryan You might want to read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/

Comment: @matt, i believe your statement in the article completely incorrect. After merging B into A (general non ff case) **all of the commits** done in B branch are presented now in A branch. No conflicts - merge commit itself is non-functional, ie doesn't contain any changes (`git show` will not show you anything). In case of any conflict, merge commit will be functional (with changes resolving conflict). Reproduced it locally.

Comment: This one quote from the article: `Git now creates, out of whole cloth, a completely new commit combining the contributions` - that merge commit is empty in case there was no any conflicts, ie **non-functional**, there are no any changes inside.

Comment: @Ryan the entire concept "commits are in a branch" is wrong. A branch is just a single commit. Of course after the merge the commits from both sides of the commit are all _reachable_ from the newly created commit; that is the point of the merge. Maybe you should start by reading my https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/ — it's best not to be operating from a false premise about what Git is.

Comment: @matt consider yours and j6t's comment，the merge op only compare the difference between two branch's working tree and the public base commit . commit a is the public base of A/B， branch A's state is no difference with commit a , so branch B has not changed anything before or after the merge op.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this history:

```
--a--a_rev1--a'      <-- branch A
   \          \
----M--a_rev2--M'    <-- branch B
```

You are observing that the changes of `a'` (which are identical to `a`) are missing from branch B.

This is expected and not an error.

When Git merges changes, it only considers the two project states at tips that are merge, `a'` on branch A and `a_rev2` on branch B, and the merge base, which is `a`. From the point of view of branch B (the "merge target"), only the changes between the merge base `a` and the other branch tip, `a'` are considered and only those changes are integrated into the "merge target". Since `a_rev1` and `a'` are changes that cancel each other out, there are actually no changes to integrate, therefore, the merge `M'` does not introduce any changes compared to the ancestor `a_rev2`.

You can also read the story like this:

1. On branch A, the developer first said "I need to revert `a`, so let's make `a_rev1`!" But then later, they said "No, wait, I do need `a`, so let's cherry-pick it, `a'`!" The effect is that we do not need any change.
2. On branch B, the developer said "We definitely need to revert `a`. Let's make `a_rev2`.
3. The branches are now merged. One side said, that no changes are needed, but the other said that some changes, `a_rev2`, are needed, so that is what remains.

Comment: so the merge op just compare the working tree without each commit on each  branch？

Comment: Yes, very correctly observed.